# What does "^a" mean in this SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql

I have found this query, but i'm not able what does it do.
I don't know what the "^a" means, particularly.

```
select distinct ?type where { 
  dbpedia:Stephen_King a ?type .
  filter not exists { 
    ?subtype ^a dbpedia:Stephen_King ;
             rdfs:subClassOf ?type .
    filter ( ?subtype != ?type )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's [a SPARQL 1.1 property path](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) which describes a route through a graph between two graph nodes, in your case it denotes the inverse path, i.e. from object to subject, thus, it's equivalent to

`dbpedia:Stephen_King a ?subtype .`

with `a` being just a shortcut for `rdf:type`

It's just used here to be able to use the more compact Turtle syntax, i.e. instead of writing

```
dbpedia:Stephen_King a ?subtype .
?subtype rdfs:subClassOf ?type .
```

you can write

```
?subtype ^a dbpedia:Stephen_King 
?subtype rdfs:subClassOf ?type .
```

and therefore since subjects are the same

```
?subtype ^a dbpedia:Stephen_King ;
         rdfs:subClassOf ?type .
```