# What the asterisk mean in this SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, ontology, triplestore

What the asterisk mean in this SPARQL query?

```
SELECT ?uri ?type
WHERE{
    ?uri a ?type.
    ?type rdfs:subClassOf* example:Device.
}
```

Does it mean "subclass of a subclass"?
Can I use it with other predicates?

Comment: Ehm, a question from my side: Have you read my answer of your first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827050/what-does-a-mean-in-this-sparql-query . There I showed you a link to SPARQL 1.1 Property Paths (https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths), right?

Comment: Yes. That reference is very good. Based on that, I think that the meaning is "subclass of a subclass". I'm just trying to confirm.

Comment: No, `p*` is the transitive closure of the property `p`, in your case `p = rdfs:subClassOf`

Answer (score 8):

An asterisk (*) after a path element means “zero or more of this element”.

If there are no other elements in the path, `?a something* ?b` means that `?b` might also just be `?a` directly, with no path elements between them at all.

```
?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?class.
# means:
?item wdt:P31 ?class
# or
?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279 ?class
# or
?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279/wdt:P279 ?class
# or
?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279/wdt:P279/wdt:P279 ?class
```

See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/Property_paths) for more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

The asterisk after a predicate means that you want to follow a property path with zero or more occurrences of rdfs:subClassOf.

Your phrase "subclass of a subclass" is about right, although I would say "subclasses of subclasses," because the * property path is recursive.  As you can see from the technical document in AKSW's comment, there are several other property path operators that go in either direction, with or without a limit on the number of occerances (or depth.)

Here's a pretty good example from Marklogic...  I think this should work within any 1.1 endpoint.

https://developer.marklogic.com/features/semantics/path-examples

Yes, property paths are applicable to any predicate/property, not just rdfs:subClassOf.